# Cypress Assertion error : has CSS property: overflow: hidden and an effective width and height of: 1423 x 0 pixels

Tags: cypress

```
it('Select each option from items per page  drop down and verify pagination for fault catalog', () => {
    // cy.wait('@faultCatalogList');
    let totalRecordCount = 0;
    const tableLocator = 'table[class="cxui-table cdk-table"]';
    // const tableLocator = 'div.responsive-table';
    const rowCountIdentifier = tableLocator + '> tbody > tr';
    // const rowCountIdentifier =
    //  'cxui-table-shell > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > table > tbody >tr';
    cy.log('Test');

    cy.get(rowCountIdentifier)
        .parents('table')
        .get('tr.cdk-row')
        .then(function ($elem) {
            cy.log('Test2');
            totalRecordCount = $elem.length;
            cy.log('Test3');
            cy.waitUntilAngularStable();
            verifyPagination(tableLocator, rowCountIdentifier, totalRecordCount);
        });
});
```

Timed out retrying after 30000ms: expected '<table.cxui-table.cdk-table>' to be 'visible'

This element <table.cxui-table.cdk-table> is not visible because its parent <div.content> has CSS property: overflow: hidden and an effective width and height of: 1423 x 0 pixels.

Comment: Where in your code is the error coming?

Comment: "verifyPagination" method has "cy.get(tableLocator).should('be.visible');"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.